# Have text above icon in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am learning React and I came across a youtube video that teaches how to use spinners.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3L4zQnLrVA

I've written the code inside of codesandbox.io here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-thunder-sise4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Now if you click on the "Fake Fetch" button, you'll see the word "Text" in black to the left of the spinner and I was wondering how I could get the word above the spinner.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following style to your `h3` with `Text`

`<h3 style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '250px' }}>Text</h3>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-borg-k3d2u

FWIW - in the future try to use StackOverflow's code snippets, since links to codesandbox aren't guaranteed to exist in the future in case someone else can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` to achieve this. In your `styled` styles, use:

```
display: "flex",
flexDirection: "column"
```

So your entire style would be:

```
const styled = props.overlay
    ? {
        background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        position: "fixed",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }
    : null;
```

Keep in mind the style above is only applied when the `overlay` is selected. Otherwise you don't apply any special styles to the Spinner (because they styles are `null`).

If you want the Text and Spinner stacked for both `overlay` and non-overlay, use:

```
const styled = props.overlay
    ? {
        background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        position: "fixed",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }
    : {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      };
```

Here's the full working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-frost-3zjob

Answer (score 0):

This definately works. Add some flex properties such as:

```
display: "flex",
flexDirection: "column",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
```

If you use the styles as such, it works perfectly.

```
import React from "react";
import SpinnerIcon from "./SpinnerIcon";
import "./Spinner.css";

const Spinner = props => {
  return (
    <div className="Spinner" style={{
      background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      position: "fixed",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
    }}>
      <h3 style={{ margin: 0 }}>Text</h3>
      <SpinnerIcon />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Spinner;
```

[Check this fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-silence-judw5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)